# Paypal : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using NVP / SOAP APIs. I use paypal sandbox. The Url which I use is :**https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp**
The code was working fine but all of a sudden it stopped working. It gives the following error **"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."**. Is there anything that is changed in paypal or am I doing something wrong. If you need more details please let me know.
Any help will be greatly appreciated